# RTOS task scheduling. Why using function pointer instead of an array for a simple cyclic scheduler?

Tags: c, rtos

Using function pointer to void function that operates on 2-d array instead of manipulating a constant array.

In a book 'Real-time systems development' by Rob Williams in chapter 4.7 a simple task scheduler is presented.

A list of tasks is defined: task_one(), task_two() etc.

The idea is to build a 2-D array of tasks and iterate through the table at constant frequency in order to execute tasks one by one.

Here is the example code:

```
#include ...

//time related variables
var1, var2
//no explicit 2-D table declaration/definition

//Tasks
void task_one() {
 ...
}

void task_two() {
 ...
}

void task_idle() {
 ...
}

//Here is the interesting part - the scheduler; why is this a function pointer (a strange one, though) and not a standard const array?
void (*ttable[2][4])() = {
 {task_one, task_two, task_idle, task_idle},
 {task_two, task_two, task_idle, task_idle}
}

int main() { 
 while (1) {
  for (slot = 0; slot < 2; slot ++) {
   for (cycle = 0; cycle < 4; cycle ++) {
    (*ttable[slot][cycle])(); // dispatch next task
   }
   //wait for a timer to jump to the next task
  }
 }
}
```

Everything is defined on compile time. I would expect the scheduler to be a

```
const tab[2][4] {{..},{..}}
```

Why complicate so much?

Comment: ? You mean why isn't it a `void (*const ttable[2][4])()` ? `why is this a function pointer` it is an array of 4 arrays of 2 pointers to functions returning void and taking unknown arguments. It is not a function pointer. And `not a standard const array` - please define "standard const array".

Comment: I might have not understood the code properly then. Let me rephrase: Why is this table of function pointers (aka scheduler) defined as [ void (*ttable[2][4])() = {{...}{...}} ] and not [ const ttable[2][4] = {{...},{...}} ] ?

Comment: It's an array of function pointers. So it's `void (*blabla)()`. Your snippet: `const tab[2][4]`  is invalid, will not compile. What is the type of `tab`? It's an array of 4 array of 2 of ?? ? It doesn't has a type. Please read up on how to declare a function pointer variable. As to answer the question "Why is this table of function pointers defined that way not the other?" it's because the standard C language defines the rules of defining function pointers array variables that way not the other. [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*ttable%5B2%5D%5B4%5D%29%28%29)

Comment: Obviously... I forgot that a C array still needs a type of element it stores... I looked up a proper declaration of an array of function pointers, and now it makes sense. Thank you.